# How to determine registry access denied root cause

Tags: permissions, registry

I have tried to run program I wrote on two Win 7 Home Premium 32 bit PC's, under admin accounts. One has SP1, one is non SP'd. Please see below for the differing process trace results of part of it's operation. How can I figure out what is stopping one PC from allowing access to both the

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System    
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

keys and values, and not the other?

[image: Works on one]

[image: Doesn't work on the other]

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem is that you dont have permissions on the specified key. Try take ownership of the key.

Comment: I made sure that both PC's gave Full access rights to the Administrators group (with regedit.exe), but didn't look at ownership... Would ownership matter in read/write operations if permissions were the same?